# Error creating a new column using a library

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

I am trying to create a new column in existing dataframe using a library.Following is the error i am getting.
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/b47j8.png)

I tried adding a new column to calculate the implied volatility of ATM options

Link to library documentation http://vollib.org/documentation/python/1.0.2/apidoc/py_vollib.black_scholes.html

Comment: You are probably using non-vectorized library. Check out https://github.com/marcdemers/py_vollib_vectorized

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the code and the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341), [edit] them into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out [ask] for more tips like how to write a good title.